Can Twilio bidirectional stream feature works for Speech input in the call?
I am trying to reduce the latency of the custom responses generated and saving it to audio file to play in twilio call but according to docs, I am confused that whether the audio file chunks could be sent to twilio back as stream and then play the audio in call for each to and fro response instead of waiting of waiting for entire audio file to generate first with complete audio?
I have tried with some code but can't share due to my organization's non disclosure agreement

Yes, it's possible to stream audio files back to Twilio via the WebSockets connection:
  //Send Audio to Twilio when Generated Audio from Eleven Labs is Complete
  elevenLabs.on("AudioReceived", (audio) => {
    ws.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        event: "media",
        streamSid,
        media: {
          payload: audio,
        },
      }),
    );
  });


This code snippet is from a sample code repository.
Keep in mind, the payload needs to fulfill the following specs:

To send media back to Twilio, you must provide a properly formatted media message.
The payload must be encoded audio/x-mulaw with a sample rate of 8000 and must be base64 encoded. The audio can be of any size.
The media messages are buffered and played in the order received. If you need to interrupt the buffered audio, send a clear message.

